# Ubuntu force resets once during each cold boot if there's at least a single USB device connected

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, reset, ubuntu-22.04

Hi there from Ukraine!

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and when I boot my PC it force resets before reaching login screen and then the second time it boots normally. This happens only during cold boot. If I just restart my PC it boots without such problem.

It's also worth mentioning that such problem happens only if there's at least a single USB device connected. It doesn't matter which device/cable or to which port. When checking system logs the only strange error I see is the following:\

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC]
```

According to [this post](https://github.com/intel/linux-intel-lts/issues/22) it's a bug in drivers/acpi/bus.c kernel file and it got fixed in 5.20 upstream. I'm not sure if it's really the cause of my resets during boot but what do you think? Do you have any suggestions? Any help is much appreciated...

Thank you in advance and have a nice day! Stay safe! ;-)

Comment: Update: applying the before-mentioned patch and rebuilding linux kernel didn't solve the problem. Neither did switching to newest available linux kernel (6.0 at the time of writing). And no, it's not a hardware issue, it's a Linux-specific problem since Windows 10 boots just fine. Dah..

Comment: I suppose if you go for Linux you should be prepared for suffering. But when suffering doesn't have a fix, that's no fun (